# SemanticException [Error 10085]: JOIN with a LATERAL VIEW is not supported 'id'

Tags: sql, join, hive, beeline

I received a code from my superiors which was working on the old Hive Cluster. I am working on a new cluster and trying to run it using beeline function on Putty 'bf mycode.sql 'throws the error:

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException
>   [Error 10085]: Line 6:24 JOIN with a LATERAL VIEW is not supported
>   'id' (state=42000, code=10085)

```
create table myTable as select distinct AtypeId
,cast(from_unixtime(t.timestamp) as date) as date
,C
,t.id
,t.marketid
from File1 LATERAL VIEW explode(eventlist) exploded_table as t
join File2
on oldID=t.id
order by AtypeId,date;
```

Any idea what I should do?

Comment: What is the version of old and new hive cluster

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing your query as below:

```
create table myTable as
select t.* from
(
  select distinct 
     AtypeId
     ,cast(from_unixtime(t.timestamp) as date) as date
     ,C
     ,t.id
     ,t.marketid
  from 
     File1 LATERAL VIEW explode(eventlist) exploded_table
) as t join File2 on oldID=t.id
order by AtypeId,date;
```

There are certain restriction on using joins and lateral view together for ex you can not do `lateral view` with `map join`.

One thing I have a doubt is, in older version it might be doing something different in the join so was not throwing any error. You need to look at `explain plan` for both versions to understand that better.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work for me. Although I solved this by splitting the function into 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone facing the issue, this worked for me.

```
create table myTable as select distinct AtypeId
,cast(from_unixtime(t.timestamp) as date) as date
,t.id
,t.marketid
from File1 LATERAL VIEW explode(eventlist) exploded_table as t
order by AtypeId,date;

create table myTable2 as select distinct AtypeId
,date
,C
,id
,marketid
from myTable
inner join File2
on oldID=id;
```